# MS-Access Auto update form constantly to change visibility of a button

Tags: database, ms-access, conditional-statements

still strugling with an access database for a quality control system.

My last question was to have a button visibility and enable properties change to 0 if a condition wasnt met. I was able to do this with the following code:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

Dim ok As Boolean
ok = Status.Value


Botão_Motores.Visible = ok
Botão_Motores.Enabled = ok

End Sub
```

But the problem now is that it only updates the status when i open and close the form, not when the Status field updates... My approach here, although im open to other strategies is to include somthing in the Change sub of the Status field to run the code in the form_current sub, is this possible or do i have to do it in another way? if so, how?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Access has no event for a datachange in the form - just for the first time the user changed any data on the form (dirty) and for record change(current) and for datachanges in the controls (Dirty, Change, BeforeUpdate,AfterUpdate...)

You can make a procedure for that task and call it from Current and from the appropriate event (probably AfterUpdate) of the controls that should change the visibility of your button.

```
Private Sub ChangeMotorVisibility()
   Botao_Motores.visible=Status.value
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
  ChangeMotorVisibility
End Sub

Private Sub Status_AfterUpdate()
  ChangeMotorVisibility
End Sub
```

Comment: that seemed like a perfect answer man, but it doesnt seem to update when the Status field changes it's value... Can you think of any other way to have the field update? i tried almost every sub both on the Status field and on the form field, no luck :/

Comment: Please give me more information then. What type is the status field? how does it get its value (is it calculated, a checkbox ...?

Comment: the status field is calculated based on a series of checkboxes, the formula is Abs([checkbox1]*[checkbox2]...[checkbox 10]) so it returns 1 only if all checkboxes return 1, thats how im doing the check, it seemed like the best way. if you can think of another way, please tell me

Comment: For boolean values you should use boolean operators. Better would be `status=[checkbox1].value AND [checkbox2].value AND ...` So if you use this in the ChangeMotorVisibility `Botao_Motores.visible=status` and in every checkboxes AfterUpdate you call ChangeMotorVisibility you should be fine.